# Why QtCompositor is failed to initialize EGL display?

Tags: qt, qtwayland

Am trying to run QWaylandCompositor example code "qwindow-compositor" on Kaby Lake system and Sky Lake system. But It shows as

> QtCompositor: Failed to initialize EGL display. Could not get EglDisplay for window.

What I need to do resolve this?

Comment: On what qt platform plugin are you running the compositor (i.e. inside X11 or another wayland compositor, or from a tty)? Also, what version of Qt do you have?

Comment: Qt Playform am using is X11. and am using Qt Creator 4.4.1
Based on Qt 5.9.3 (GCC 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6), 64 bit)

Comment: You're most likely getting this because you're running it within X11, please update your question so my answer below makes sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the README

> Testing a Qt-based compositor on X11:
>
> Most QWidget-based applications will use shared memory buffers, which work on
>   all hardware. OpenGL and Qt Quick applications need a way to send graphics
>   memory buffers from client to server. There are many options, and not all
>   options work on all hardware.
>
> The X Composite buffer integration should work on all modern X servers. It
>   can be used with either EGL or GLX as the OpenGL backend. This must match the
>   backend used by the xcb platform plugin. (Normally GLX is the default for Qt
>   applications running on X11.) To use the X Composite buffer sharing with EGL,
>   start the compositor as follows:
>
> ```
> QT_XCB_GL_INTEGRATION=xcb_egl QT_WAYLAND_CLIENT_BUFFER_INTEGRATION=xcomposite-egl ./pure-qml
> ```

Just exchange `pure-qml` with `qwindow-compositor`

Answer (score 1):

In my case following libraries were missing on my system

```
libgles2-mesa libgles2-mesa-dev
```